# Network communication between Windows + WSL2 + Docker

Tags: windows, docker, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a web app hosted in a Docker container and exposes port 5050 that is mapped to port 80 of the container.
The web app listens on 0.0.0.0:5050.
The Docker engine runs on WSL2.

Now when I open a browser on Windows and go to http://localhost:5050, everything works and I can see the web app.

But I don't understand how the request can reach the Docker container when I navigate to localhost on Windows.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Docker for Windows uses a [WSL2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/), and is integrated with WSL distros.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not use Docker desktops. The Docker engine was directly installed within Ubuntu that runs inside wsl.

Comment: It seems that since version build 18945 of Windows, it is now possible to access app that runs inside of WSL using 'localhost' as if it runs on Windows. This probably explains that we can access to running container within WSL via 'localhost'. Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking